# How to restore by-default saved 'sys' database in MySQL 8.0?

Tags: mysql, sys

By mistake I deleted by-default saved 'sys' database in Mysql version 8.0.21 So, how to restore it?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how it was saved, but there's an example at the bottom of the [manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sys-schema-usage.html)

```
mysql < sys_dump.sql
```